# Illustrator/photoshop: give stroke sharp corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, path, image-trace

Here is what I want. This is the image I got.

[image]

and I do outline by first creating the pen outline.. then stroking by brush. this is what i get:

[image]

but i want the all edges pointed. For example like this:. 
(Here I am doing some edges but I want all)
[image]

so i have to do it manually. Is there any easier way to do this ?

PS: I am so noob in designing, I even dont know what to write in the title

Comment: I would actually start in photoshop, make the image high contrast (poss. black and white) and then take it into illustrator and image trace it.

Comment: Can you please guide me with screenshots?

Comment: Just a question - how close to the original do you want to go? As close as possible, or do you prefer the stroke to be an approximate, as per your images?

Comment: I want to get smooth trace you can say..

Comment: What version of PS?

Comment: I don't understand the question. First - Please clarify -- Are you using Photoshop or Illustrator, it *does* matter? Second, why are you using a "brush" and what "brush" are you using? How is your sample path "painted" is it in Illustrator or Photoshop? What are the stroke options? In AI, what's the Appearance Panel look like with the stroke selected? Please show the path *selected* so that anchor points are visible.

Comment: Right now i am using Photoshop as i am more comfortable with it but i have illustrator with me so i can use that too. I am using brush coz i don't know what else too use. Please guide me. I am using simple brush. But I have tried different dynamic brushes like round point, flat point with different combinations but with no luck. I used no stroke options.. But using dynamic brush, i have checked stimulated pressure. And till now i have not use AI in this project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading comments under the question....

Photoshop has *basic* path editing capabilities. That is not to say they are lacking for the most part, but there are some areas which Photoshop is not as robust as Illustrator. Remember vector items are an *addition* to Photoshop, not it's core goal.

**For Photoshop**, you need to use the **Pen Tool** to draw a **vector layer**. This means you need to use Photoshop CS6 or newer. You can then add a stroke to that vector layer and move the stroke to the *inside* of the vector shape. This will force the stroke to have the corners you draw as opposed to rounding everything.

[image]

In many cases the strokes can cause extreme corner miters like this:

[image]

There's not a lot you can do about those other than to edit the path and ensure the corners aren't *that* tight of an angle. This is where Photoshop can fail with paths at times. You'll notice in the image above there are a couple sharp corners that are a bit *too* extended. There's no way to solve that other than to alter the angles at the corner by reducing/enlarging the amount of curve on the associated paths.

You do *not* want to use a brush and then use `Edit > Stroke...`. This will *never* get sharp corners. You *could* use a layer style with a stroke, provided the stroke is also *aligned to the inside* of the shape.

**For Illustrator,** It's a simple matter of drawing your shape.

Illustrator provides specific adjustment to miter limits. This allows you to somewhat control how and when points become sharp:

[image]
[image]

You can also align the stroke to the inside using Illustrator (for closed paths). This generally results in a better stroke than Photoshop provides.

[image]

---

This was originally a 2014 answer. However....

## as of *February 2020*...

....nothing has changed with respect to Photoshop and this answer.

Comment: wow.. thats a great help man.. you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how high fidelity you want, I actually think this is the easiest way: think of the shape you are making as a *shape*, not a stroke.

In Illustrator, draw - with the *pencil* - a thin outline. Then you can have a filled shape, or alter the thickness of the pencil stroke.

[image]

[image]

For something in higher fidelity, particularly if you want the entire image in its component parts, start in Photoshop. We have others posts explaining this in detail, I will try to find one.

**[Convert a line drawing to vector](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector/1371#1371)**

[**Making a line drawing or vector from image**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8728/making-a-line-drawing-or-vector-image-from-photograph/15952#15952)

**Edit**

Working a little on the line above, for high fidelity, this might be the result.

[image]

If you want it *less* high fidelity, I suggest the same method, but with less fidelity in the choice of shape.

**Edit 2**

Stick to the pencil tool:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help but smoothness is required... Something like this is what i want https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_Or1EdQ3IkSMGJwTzNvNUtiUzQ/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but you will have to work on that line regardless of method. The image you have is very bitmap-y, and you will not get a smooth line in one step.

Comment: That's why i am drawing with pen tool.. Is there any way to get sharp/pointed edges?

Comment: Ok, so you basically want a pretty stylised version of the original?

Comment: Okay let me explain this a little bit.. The original image here is the scan of blanket. and due to stuff off blanket , printing is blurred.. The image fed in the machine was pretty smooth.. Like the Link i posted in comments.. So i have to make that.. Now if it seems stylish to you sir, it's a compliment ;)

Comment: heehe - madam, actually. And stylised, not stylish :). Basically: stick to the _pencil_ tool and you should get what you want.

Comment: :O My bad :p.. And i don't get it.. What should i change in my workflow..

Comment: (no worries on the sir-thing. Used to it.) You say: "outline by first creating the pen outline.. then stroking by brush". Skip the brush-stuff. Use the pencil, and alter the thickness as desired. Then it is entirely down to your handiwork to get rounded bits and really pointy bits. You will need to clean it up a little afterwards by using direct selection tool and/or remove some vector points.

Comment: What i got is this by using pen tool.. Not much success https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_Or1EdQ3IkSeHM2QWtpYzVpWE0/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Here is a potential misunderstanding. I am talking about _Illustrator_, you might be talking about _Photoshop_?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Illustrator: Draw the lines/shapes with the pencil tool;
2. Add Stroke to the line for your desired thickness & color;
3. Select the line, click "Expand" (stroked line is converted to shape with anchor points);
4. Use "Delete Anchor Point" tool to remove one anchor where you want the pointed tip - going from two anchors to one will create sharp tip;

(worked for me)

chef

Comment: Welcome to gd.SE! You could do that, but the question is about doing it automatically, not manually.