# Different behaviour of sharp corners in illustrator strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an Illustrator design which has a part that looks as follows:

[image: Picture]

However, I have applied same settings to the three independent paths:

[image: Stroke menu]

That is the stroke menu. You can see that the vertex settings are the same (I did it both selecting each path separately and selecting them together). I would like the three endings to be equal, so I could choose which ending shape I like the most. Also, when the stroke is set to be filled strictly inside the path, and not over it, the stroke of the side lines converge at a higher point than that of their upper correspondent object (the whole design is a diamond):
[image: Full diamond]

That might be because the angle is sharper, though. I think that something has to be wrong with the lower triangle shapes on the sides, but I can't really find out what. The object is a compound path, I don't know if that might help.

Comment: Sort of the reverse of this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39211/illustrator-photoshop-give-stroke-sharp-corners --- But the answer I provided there explains *why*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the miter limit  value. I have circled the option in your own image.

[image]

If you make the number higher then it does this to even higher angles. Quite technically without a miter limit he system could be forced to draw a really big miter.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed – the reason for this is that Illustrator disables sharp vertices when the angle formed by the two lines tangent to the curve by the left and right sides of an anchor point is lower than a specific value (which I really don't care very much to know exactly). I found out trying to move the anchors around the document and I suddenly saw that the sharp ending showed up.

Hope this might be helpful to anyone having the same problem

Comment: There is actually a 'limit' value in the stroke palette that controls exactly when Illustrator truncates your vertex.

Comment: Ahhh that is the box over there! Got it – thank you very much @Vincent